# How do I test for collisions between two concave shapes decomposed into collections of convex polyhedra?

Tags: java, separating-axis-theorem, convex

I am using convex decomposition with SAT (separating axis theorem) and I generate two arrays of convex pieces, How do I submit my arrays to my collision detection method which only takes two arguments.

```
public MTV testCollision(BroadPhasePair pair) {
    Entity entity = pair.getBody();
    Entity id1 = pair.getBody();

    List<Convex> entityConvex = ConvexDecomposer.decompose(entity);
    List<Convex> id1Convex = ConvexDecomposer.decompose(id1);
    return null;
}

private MTV testCollision(Convex body,Convex id1) {
    float overlap = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    Vector3f smallest = null;
    Vector3f[] axis1 = body.getAxis();
    Vector3f[] axis2 = id1.getAxis();

    for(Vector3f axis : axis1) {
        Projection p1 = body.project(axis);
        Projection p2 = id1.project(axis);

        if(!p1.overlapps(p2)) return null;
            float o = p1.getOverlap(p2);
            if(o < overlap) {
                overlap = o;
                smallest = axis;

        }
    }

    for(Vector3f axis : axis2) {
        Projection p1 = body.project(axis);
        Projection p2 = id1.project(axis);

        if(!p1.overlapps(p2)) {
            return null;
        }else {
            float o = p1.getOverlap(p2);
            if(o < overlap) {    
                overlap = o;
                smallest = axis;
            }
        }
    }

    MTV mtv = new MTV(smallest, overlap);
    return null;


}
```

I want to be able to somehow submit my array into the testCollision method.

Comment: Note that you'll want to do your decomposition step once, up-front, at bake time or load time, and cache the resulting array for re-use. If you do it inside the test collision method every time you want to check for collisions, you'll end up performing a lot of redundant work.

Comment: @DMGregory so when I create the entities decompose the meshes then. This could could solve a lot of problems I've been having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to take every part of one body and check them against every part of the other body. Then you'll have a list of MTVs, which you need to get the smallest of the same way you do it in the SAT function (the one with the smallest overlap is the one you need)

Comment: but if you had more parts in one body than in another what then would you do.

Comment: @TheMaskedRebel As I said "you just need to take every part of one body and check them against every part of the other body". That's body parts in the first time body parts in the second amount of checks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to help people who get stuck like me.

```
public MTV testCollision(BroadPhasePair pair) {
    Entity entity = pair.getBody();
    Entity id1 = pair.getBody();

    List<Convex> entityConvex = entity.getConvexes();
    List<Convex> id1Convex = id1.getConvexes();
    MTV mtv = null;
    float overlap = Float.MAX_VALUE;

    for(int i = 0; i< entityConvex.size();i++) {

        for(int j = 0;j < id1Convex.size();j++) {
            Convex convex = entityConvex.get(i);
            Convex convex2 = id1Convex.get(j);

            MTV temp = testCollision(convex, convex2);

            if(temp != null) {
                if(temp.getOverlap() < overlap) {
                    mtv = temp;
                    overlap = temp.getOverlap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return mtv;
}

private MTV testCollision(Convex body,Convex id1) {
    float overlap = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    Vector3f smallest = null;
    Vector3f[] axis1 = body.getAxis();
    Vector3f[] axis2 = id1.getAxis();

    for(Vector3f axis : axis1) {
        Projection p1 = body.project(axis);
        Projection p2 = id1.project(axis);

        if(!p1.overlapps(p2)) return null;
            float o = p1.getOverlap(p2);
            if(o < overlap) {
                overlap = o;
                smallest = axis;

        }
    }

    for(Vector3f axis : axis2) {
        Projection p1 = body.project(axis);
        Projection p2 = id1.project(axis);

        if(!p1.overlapps(p2)) {
            return null;
        }else {
            float o = p1.getOverlap(p2);
            if(p1.contains(p2) || p2.contains(p1)) {
                float min = abs(p1.getMin() - p2.getMin());
                float max = abs(p1.getMax() - p2.getMax());

                if(min < max) {
                    o += min;
                }else {
                    o += max;
                }
            }

            if(o < overlap) {
                overlap = o;
                smallest = axis;
            }

        }
    }

    MTV mtv = new MTV(smallest, overlap);
    return mtv;


}
```